# Diagram: Div hover then Displays Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, hover

**ANSWERED:** Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4o6mn3pm/16/)

I have a Diagram (a .png image) that is placed in a 350x350px square positioned in the centre of the window.

I then have 5 div boxes in a fixed position all around the window.

What I am trying to achieve is: the original Diagram will be visible, until the mouse hovers over a div box of written content to which will replace the original Diagram with a new Diagram in the exact same position as the original Diagram in the 350x350px square.

**EDITED:** What I am trying to achieve is: the original Diagram will be visible, until the mouse hovers over a div box of written content to which will replace the original Diagram with a new Diagram in the exact same position as the original Diagram in the 350x350px square. 
Then once the mouse has left that Div box of written content the original Diagram is shown.

Would I just need to create an `if` statement reverting the `display` proptery back to `none`?

I have created this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4o6mn3pm/3/) for a basic skeleton.

I thought I was on the right track using the jquery below, but I can not seem to get it to work?

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $diagram1 = $('.p1'),
      $diagram2 = $('.p2'),
      $diagram3 = $('.p3'),
      $diagram4 = $('.p4'),
      $diagram5 = $('.p5');

  $('.content-1').hover(function(){
    $diagram1.css(['display':'block']);
  });

  $('.content-2').hover(function(){
    $diagram2.css(['display':'block']);
  });

  $('.content-3').hover(function(){
    $diagram3.css(['display':'block']);
  });

  $('.content-4').hover(function(){
    $diagram4.css(['display':'block']);
  });

  $('.content-5').hover(function(){
    $diagram5.css(['display':'block']);
  });
});
```

Comment: See my answer it exactly does what you want.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your extremely fast response. I didn't exactly explain myself correctly (sorry about that ) but I have now edited my post.

@KawineshSK you're answer is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you

Comment: No problem just mark it as answered :)

Comment: Done, Can I ask why there has been made an extra `var` called `$image` when it hasn't been used in the jquery?

Comment: sorry you can delete it it was for my reference.

Comment: I just thought of another approach.. If you wouldn't mind taking a look at my updated Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4o6mn3pm/15/

would you suggest sticking with the `display` property or going with the new `opacity` property that I have implemented on Diagram1? @KawineshSK

Comment: `opacity` looks better than `display` so you can proceed with `opactity` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $diagram1 = $('.p1'),
        $diagram2 = $('.p2'),
        $diagram3 = $('.p3'),
        $diagram4 = $('.p4'),
        $diagram5 = $('.p5'),
        $image=$('.image_container img');

    $('.content-1').mouseover(function(){

        $diagram1.css('display','block');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $diagram1.css('display','none');
    });

     $('.content-2').mouseover(function(){
        $diagram2.css('display','block');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $diagram2.css('display','none');
    });

     $('.content-3').mouseover(function(){
        $diagram3.css('display','block');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $diagram3.css('display','none');
    });

     $('.content-4').mouseover(function(){
        $diagram4.css('display','block');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $diagram4.css('display','none');
    });

     $('.content-5').mouseover(function(){
        $diagram5.css('display','block');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $diagram5.css('display','none');
    });
});
```

1. The `.css()` api syntax was wrong it should be `.css('display','block');` and not `.css(['display':'block']);`
2. You could use `mouseover` and `mouseenter` to have easy way of fullfilling your task instead of `hover`

[JSFiddle-DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4o6mn3pm/10/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to make other images invisible when you are hovering over a certain div. image 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.  all are overlapping each other. if you take your mouse over image 2 then you need to make image 1,3,4,5 invisible. you can add the visibility: hidden in the jquery you made.

```
$('.content-1').hover(function(){

    $diagram5.css(['display':'block']);
    //get visibility code here
});
```

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

on

```
$diagram5.css(['display':'block']);
```

maybe it should be like this

```
$diagram5.css('display','block');
```

answered fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aswzen/4o6mn3pm/6/

and then to make it reversible you have to put the original state display on each block again, like a lamp switches. But if you do this using the `display property`, probably you're doing it wrong.

Full working filddle as you wish: http://jsfiddle.net/aswzen/4o6mn3pm/11/

but not recommended

Answer (score 0):

To `Set a` CSS Property

```
$("p").css("background-color", "yellow");
```

To `Set Multiple` CSS Properties

To set multiple CSS properties, use the following syntax:

```
css({"propertyname":"value","propertyname":"value",...});
```

[Detail](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp)

replace `[]` to `{}` like

```
$('.content-5').hover(function(){
    $diagram5.css({'display':'block'});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change the `css` syntax then you have to hide all the other images before showing the correct one.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
var $diagram1 = $('.p1'),
    $diagram2 = $('.p2'),
    $diagram3 = $('.p3'),
    $diagram4 = $('.p4'),
    $diagram5 = $('.p5');

$('.content-1').hover(function(){
    hide();
    $diagram1.css('display','block');
});

 $('.content-2').hover(function(){
     hide();
    $diagram2.css('display','block');
});

 $('.content-3').hover(function(){
     hide();
    $diagram3.css('display','block');
});

 $('.content-4').hover(function(){
     hide();
   $diagram4.css('display','block');
});

 $('.content-5').hover(function(){
     hide();
    $diagram5.css('display','block');
});
function hide()
{
    $(".p1,.p2,.p3,.p4,.p5").css("display","none");
}
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4o6mn3pm/8/)

Answer (score 0):

The Change display to block using jquery has some problem.
Simply change

```
  $diagram1.css(['display':'block']);
```

to

```
     $diagram1.css("display", "block");


  /**Working fiddle**/
```

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/hpb5oa8j/)